# Get result data context in an OnFastEval event in DWScript

Tags: delphi, dwscript

How do you get an IDataContext for the result value in the OnFastEval event in a TDWSUnit function?

The "magic functions"-functionality presented through the OnFastEval event can't return complex data, like records, as OnFastEval returns a Variant. The internal magic functions do support using an IDataContext interface to return complex data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return the `IDataContext` interface through the variant result (it's an `IUnknown`, so you can assign it directly).

You can allocate an `IDataContext` directly from `TDataContext`, from execution pool through (`args.Exec.Stack.CreateDataContext`), or you can pass along an existing one.

For sample code, see FuncFastPoint in UdwsUnitTests